# ITK DICOM series registration

Tags: registration, dicom, itk

I am trying to read in two different sets of DICOM image series in two different folders and perform a registration. The series seems to be read in correctly, everything goes smoothly until registration->Update() is being called. It crushes directly and likely an abort function is called inside Update(). The program was working fine with 2D images. Here is the code

```
   #include "itkImageRegistrationMethod.h"
   #include "itkMeanSquaresImageToImageMetric.h"

   #include "itkTimeProbesCollectorBase.h"
   #include "itkMemoryProbesCollectorBase.h"

   #include "itkBSplineTransform.h"
   #include "itkLBFGSBOptimizer.h"

   #include "itkImageFileReader.h"
   #include "itkImageFileWriter.h"

   #include "itkResampleImageFilter.h"
   #include "itkCastImageFilter.h"
   #include "itkSquaredDifferenceImageFilter.h"

   #include "itkGDCMImageIO.h"
   #include "itkGDCMSeriesFileNames.h"
   #include "itkNumericSeriesFileNames.h"
   #include "gdcmUIDGenerator.h"

   #include "itkImageSeriesReader.h"
   #include "itkImageSeriesWriter.h"

   #define SRI

   #include "itkCommand.h"
   class CommandIterationUpdate : public itk::Command
   {
   public:
     typedef  CommandIterationUpdate   Self;
     typedef  itk::Command             Superclass;
     typedef itk::SmartPointer<Self>   Pointer;
     itkNewMacro( Self );
   protected:
     CommandIterationUpdate() {};
   public:
     typedef itk::LBFGSBOptimizer       OptimizerType;
     typedef   const OptimizerType *    OptimizerPointer;

     void Execute(itk::Object *caller, const itk::EventObject & event)
       {
       Execute( (const itk::Object *)caller, event);
       }

     void Execute(const itk::Object * object, const itk::EventObject & event)
       {
       OptimizerPointer optimizer =
         dynamic_cast< OptimizerPointer >( object );
       if( !(itk::IterationEvent().CheckEvent( &event )) )
         {
         return;
         }
       std::cout << optimizer->GetCurrentIteration() << "   ";
       std::cout << optimizer->GetValue() << "   ";
       std::cout << optimizer->GetInfinityNormOfProjectedGradient() << std::endl;
       }
   };


   int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
   {
     if( argc < 4 )
       {
       std::cerr << "Missing Parameters " << std::endl;
       std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv[0];
       std::cerr << " fixedImageFile  movingImageFile outputImagefile  ";
       std::cerr << " [differenceOutputfile] [differenceBeforeRegistration] ";
       std::cerr << " [deformationField] ";
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

     const    unsigned int    ImageDimension = 3;
     typedef  float           PixelType;

     typedef itk::Image< PixelType, ImageDimension >  FixedImageType;
     typedef itk::Image< PixelType, ImageDimension >  MovingImageType;


     const unsigned int SpaceDimension = ImageDimension;
     const unsigned int SplineOrder = 3;
     typedef double CoordinateRepType;

     typedef itk::BSplineTransform<
                               CoordinateRepType,
                               SpaceDimension,
                               SplineOrder >     TransformType;

     typedef itk::LBFGSBOptimizer       OptimizerType;

     typedef itk::MeanSquaresImageToImageMetric<
                                       FixedImageType,
                                       MovingImageType >    MetricType;

     typedef itk:: LinearInterpolateImageFunction<
                                       MovingImageType,
                                       double          >    InterpolatorType;

     typedef itk::ImageRegistrationMethod<
                                       FixedImageType,
                                       MovingImageType >    RegistrationType;

     MetricType::Pointer         metric        = MetricType::New();
     OptimizerType::Pointer      optimizer     = OptimizerType::New();
     InterpolatorType::Pointer   interpolator  = InterpolatorType::New();
     RegistrationType::Pointer   registration  = RegistrationType::New();

     registration->SetMetric(        metric        );
     registration->SetOptimizer(     optimizer     );
     registration->SetInterpolator(  interpolator  );

     TransformType::Pointer  transform = TransformType::New();
     registration->SetTransform( transform );

   #ifdef SRI
     typedef itk::ImageSeriesReader< FixedImageType > FixedImageReaderType;
     typedef itk::ImageSeriesReader< MovingImageType > MovingImageReaderType;

     typedef itk::GDCMImageIO ImageIOType;
     typedef itk::GDCMSeriesFileNames InputNamesGeneratorType;
     typedef itk::NumericSeriesFileNames OutputNameGeneratorType;
     typedef itk::ImageSeriesWriter< MovingImageType, MovingImageType >             SeriesWriterType;

     ImageIOType::Pointer gdcmIO = ImageIOType::New();

     InputNamesGeneratorType::Pointer fixedImageNames = InputNamesGeneratorType::New();
     InputNamesGeneratorType::Pointer movingImageNames =        InputNamesGeneratorType::New();

     fixedImageNames->SetInputDirectory( argv[1] );
     movingImageNames->SetInputDirectory( argv[2] );

     const FixedImageReaderType::FileNamesContainer & fixedNames = fixedImageNames-       >GetInputFileNames();
     const MovingImageReaderType::FileNamesContainer & movingNames = movingImageNames->GetInputFileNames();

   #else
     typedef itk::ImageFileReader< FixedImageType  > FixedImageReaderType;
     typedef itk::ImageFileReader< MovingImageType > MovingImageReaderType;
   #endif

     FixedImageReaderType::Pointer  fixedImageReader  = FixedImageReaderType::New();
     MovingImageReaderType::Pointer movingImageReader = MovingImageReaderType::New();

   #ifdef SRI
     fixedImageReader->SetImageIO( gdcmIO );
     movingImageReader->SetImageIO( gdcmIO );

     fixedImageReader->SetFileNames( fixedNames );
     movingImageReader->SetFileNames( movingNames );

   #else
     fixedImageReader->SetFileName(  argv[1] );
     movingImageReader->SetFileName( argv[2] );
   #endif

     FixedImageType::ConstPointer fixedImage = fixedImageReader->GetOutput();

     registration->SetFixedImage(  fixedImage   );
     registration->SetMovingImage(   movingImageReader->GetOutput()   );

     fixedImageReader->Update();

     FixedImageType::RegionType fixedRegion = fixedImage->GetBufferedRegion();

    registration->SetFixedImageRegion( fixedRegion );

     typedef TransformType::RegionType RegionType;

     unsigned int numberOfGridNodes = 8;

     TransformType::PhysicalDimensionsType   fixedPhysicalDimensions;
     TransformType::MeshSizeType             meshSize;
     TransformType::OriginType               fixedOrigin;

     for( unsigned int i=0; i< SpaceDimension; i++ )
       {
       fixedOrigin = fixedImage->GetOrigin()[i];
       fixedPhysicalDimensions[i] = fixedImage->GetSpacing()[i] *
         static_cast<double>(
         fixedImage->GetLargestPossibleRegion().GetSize()[i] - 1 );
       }
     meshSize.Fill( numberOfGridNodes - SplineOrder );

     transform->SetTransformDomainOrigin( fixedOrigin );
     transform->SetTransformDomainPhysicalDimensions(
       fixedPhysicalDimensions );
     transform->SetTransformDomainMeshSize( meshSize );
     transform->SetTransformDomainDirection( fixedImage->GetDirection() );

     typedef TransformType::ParametersType     ParametersType;

     const unsigned int numberOfParameters =
                  transform->GetNumberOfParameters();

     ParametersType parameters( numberOfParameters );

     parameters.Fill( 0.0 );

     transform->SetParameters( parameters );

     registration->SetInitialTransformParameters( transform->GetParameters() );

     std::cout << "Intial Parameters = " << std::endl;
     std::cout << transform->GetParameters() << std::endl;

     OptimizerType::BoundSelectionType boundSelect( transform->GetNumberOfParameters()        );
     OptimizerType::BoundValueType upperBound( transform->GetNumberOfParameters() );
     OptimizerType::BoundValueType lowerBound( transform->GetNumberOfParameters() );

     boundSelect.Fill( 0 );
     upperBound.Fill( 0.0 );
     lowerBound.Fill( 0.0 );

     optimizer->SetBoundSelection( boundSelect );
     optimizer->SetUpperBound( upperBound );
     optimizer->SetLowerBound( lowerBound );

     optimizer->SetCostFunctionConvergenceFactor( 1e+12 );
     optimizer->SetProjectedGradientTolerance( 1.0 );
     optimizer->SetMaximumNumberOfIterations( 500 );
     optimizer->SetMaximumNumberOfEvaluations( 500 );
     optimizer->SetMaximumNumberOfCorrections( 5 );

     CommandIterationUpdate::Pointer observer = CommandIterationUpdate::New();
     optimizer->AddObserver( itk::IterationEvent(), observer );

     itk::TimeProbesCollectorBase chronometer;
     itk::MemoryProbesCollectorBase memorymeter;

     std::cout << std::endl << "Starting Registration" << std::endl;

     try
       {
       memorymeter.Start( "Registration" );
       chronometer.Start( "Registration" );

       registration->Update();

       chronometer.Stop( "Registration" );
       memorymeter.Stop( "Registration" );

       std::cout << "Optimizer stop condition = "
                 << registration->GetOptimizer()->GetStopConditionDescription()
                 << std::endl;
       }
     catch( itk::ExceptionObject & err )
       {
       std::cerr << "ExceptionObject caught !" << std::endl;
       std::cerr << err << std::endl;
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
       }

     OptimizerType::ParametersType finalParameters =
                       registration->GetLastTransformParameters();

     std::cout << "Last Transform Parameters" << std::endl;
     std::cout << finalParameters << std::endl;


     // Report the time taken by the registration
     chronometer.Report( std::cout );
     memorymeter.Report( std::cout );

     transform->SetParameters( finalParameters );

     // resample and output
```

I have been struggling on this for weeks and still couldn't figure what is the problem. I tried to look up in the user guide and examples but none of them is reading DICOM image series.

It would also be helpful if anyone could provide me with an example of ITK registration on image series.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running this under 32 bit windows or compiling for 32 bits. I ask because normally a 32 bit program is limited to a 2GB fragmented address space (regardless of the amount of ram or swap you have) which could quickly be exhausted in a case of 2X 3D DICOM + float images.

Answer (score 0):

If you're uncertain that the DICOM series are read in correctly maybe you should try to test that part of the code first. I've used a similar example without problems. However, I read in both DICOM series and wrote them to a 3D dataset and then performed the registration. This might help out.